# Resize NSWindows with easing animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nswindow

I'm trying to resize an NSWindow (the main one) with a nice easing animation (EaseOut).

I can use the `[NSWindow animator]` but I havn't found a way to add the easing effect.

Do you have an idea or code sample which can help me to do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
float Y = 100;
float X = 200;

NSRect frame = [window frame];

frame.origin.y -= Y;
frame.size.height += Y;
frame.size.width += X;

[window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

**Option 2**

```
float Y = 100;
float X = 200;

NSRect frame = [window frame];

frame.origin.y -= Y;
frame.size.height += Y;
frame.size.width += X;

NSDictionary *windowResize = @{
    NSViewAnimationTargetKey: window,
    NSViewAnimationEndFrameKey: [NSValue valueWithRect:frame]
};
NSDictionary *oldFadeOut = @{
    NSViewAnimationTargetKey: [NSNull null],
    NSViewAnimationEffectKey: NSViewAnimationFadeOutEffect
};
NSDictionary *newFadeIn = @{
    NSViewAnimationTargetKey: [NSNull null],
    NSViewAnimationEffectKey: NSViewAnimationFadeInEffect
};

NSArray *animations = @[windowResize, newFadeIn, oldFadeOut];
NSViewAnimation *animation = [[NSViewAnimation alloc] initWithViewAnimations: animations];

[animation setAnimationBlockingMode: NSAnimationBlocking];
[animation setAnimationCurve: NSAnimationEaseIn];
[animation setDuration: 2];     
[animation startAnimation];
```

Comment: Hi Anne, thanks for the snippet but with your solution I don't have the nice easing effect, do you have an idea?

Comment: Using `animate:YES` makes it nice and smooth. Please clarify the _"nice easing effect"_ you require.

Comment: What I'm referring to is the *Animation Pacing* you can see in this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html)

Comment: Added working snippet using `NSAnimation` and `NSAnimationEaseIn`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

I was just missing the `[animation setAnimationCurve: NSAnimationEaseIn];` part.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: For the past few hours I've been looking for a way to animate an NSWindow's size without simultaneously blocking any other UI animations, and option #2 (with NSAnimationNonblocking) did the job. Thank you!

Comment: Please leave Anne's update in place. It works. Modernising it for so-called 'clarity' only introduced 3 compiler bugs and was therefore of no value.

Comment: What do we need the 'newFadeIn' and 'oldFadeOut' dictionaries for? In my testing the animation still works the exact same when you remove them.

Answer (score -6):

```
[[NSWindow animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
```

Don't forget to set the alpha value to 1.0 when you want to show the window again.

Comment: That'll hide the window. Plus you should hide it (for real) when done with the opacity animation via `setHidden:YES`. But that's not at all related to window resizing??