# Xcode: window animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, animation, window

I'm wondering how to make a window "grow" like the Xcode's one when it opens...
(of course I'm using Xcode to make that window, and I'm on Mountain Lion)

Comment: I was not aware that the Xcode window did fade in? What are you talking about? Perhaps a screenshot or something. Of course, you could still do that on your app, I just don't believe Xcode does. Oh, and you mean on Cocoa right?

Comment: I don't know how Xcode 4 behaves on Lion, but it fades on Mountain Lion. Yes, I'm talking about Cocoa

Comment: I'm on Mountain Lion, but it does not fade. I just opened and closed the window multiple times.

Comment: Maybe you used Onyx to kill the animations?

Comment: Wait. I see. That is not fading, it is just an animation that extends the window from nothing, out.

Comment: LOL you're right, I used I wrong verb. Thank you

Comment: So the question is, do you want fading, or that "growing" animation?

Comment: This is weird. This should be easy. Almost every big app uses it. Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird, Xcode. Hmm...

Comment: I would suggest following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953802/window-animation-in-mountain-lion-not-always-showing-upon-orderfront

Answer (score 1):

For starters look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSViewAnimation. Despite its name, it works on windows as well.

You can also look here: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AnimatedWindowOpening

EDIT

I haven't tried this, but it looks promising. `animationResizeTime:` part of NSWindow, I believe should change the animation time. Now, I am assuming that all window actually have this animation, which I read somewhere that it does, however Xcode has extended the time. Perhaps .2 seconds wasn't enough.

That might only work if you use this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setFrame:display:animate:

Good luck.

**Edit**

According to CodaFi, you can simply use this in the Interface Builder. Select your window and change this setting. However, I can not seem to get that too work. Therefore I am running out of ideas. You could also look at this, although not exactly what you mentioned, it may guide the right way: [Resize NSWindows with easing animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225398/resize-nswindows-with-easing-animation)

[image: Solution]

Comment: NSViewAnimation is an oversight IMHO.  It should be deprecated.  Also, there's a much simpler, system controller way, to animate windows the way he describes.

Comment: I was actually hoping there was. Are you aware of it. That is all I know, thought I would at least share my knowledge. However, it does seem like there should be an easier way.

Comment: In IB, you can specify the window to animate in like a document.  That's the easiest way.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I was wondering what the Document Animation was. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: maybe this settings works only in conjunction with other settings...

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I'll look more at it later, but you should look at animationResizeTime:. Perhaps the time is to short.

Comment: Man. What is with people downvoting my answers. I gave all kinds of ways to solve this. I don't think that deserves a downvote.